# Running a linear regression between an array(n,1) and a matrix(n,2)

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a linear regression between `Effective Federal Funds Rate` and the Unemployment Rate`and`Inflation Rate` columns. I keep getting this error"

```
TypeError: first argument must be iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load the two CSV files into dataframes
df1 = pd.read_csv('index.csv', sep=',')
X=df1["Effective Federal Funds Rate"]
inflation_rate=df1["Inflation Rate"]
Unemployment_Rate=df1["Unemployment Rate"]
y=pd.concat(Unemployment_Rate,inflation_rate)
X.dropna(axis=0)
X.dropna(axis=0)
# Create a linear regression model and fit it to the data
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

# Print the coefficients of the linear regression model
print('Coefficient: ', model.coef_)
print('Intercept: ', model.intercept_)
r_squared = model.score(X, y)
print('Coefficient of determination (R^2): ', r_squared)
# Plot the data points and the linear regression line
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X, model.predict(X), color='red')
plt.xlabel('Interest rates')
plt.ylabel('Natural Gas Opening Price ($)')
plt.show()
```

Am I doing a logic error or a syntax error?
The end result should be a plot to analyze the relationship between the two input elements.

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: Try `X=df1[["Effective Federal Funds Rate"]]` instead of `X=df1["Effective Federal Funds Rate"]` so you get a dataframe instead of a series.

Comment: THere are some Nan Values i'm not sure if they are causing the error

Comment: You need to pass a sequence of pandas object in pd.concat, change this `y=pd.concat(Unemployment_Rate,inflation_rate)` to this `y=pd.concat([Unemployment_Rate,inflation_rate])`

Comment: ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). ----- line (model.fit)

Comment: You need to replace nan values with some default before passing it to fit, see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html